# Inequality of Hausdorff measures for convex sets $\mathfrak{H}^{n-1}(\partial E)\le \mathfrak{H}^{n-1}(\partial F)$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I'm preparing for an exam on the calculus of variations and I need help in solving this exercise from an old exam text (actually it's only a part of a bigger exercise but its parts are quite independent): I don't know where to start and any help would be welcomed.

> Given two nonempty convex subsets $E\subset F\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $n\ge 2$ , prove that
>   $\mathfrak{H}^{n-1}(\partial E)\le \mathfrak{H}^{n-1}(\partial F).$
>   (In fact, the convexity of $F$ is not needed.)

Here $\partial E$ is the boundary of the set $E$ and $\mathfrak{H}$ is the standard Hausdorff measure i.e. the measure defined as
$$\newcommand{\diam}{\operatorname{diam}}
\mathfrak{H}^d(E)=\liminf_{\underset{\{U_i\}_{i}:\bigcup_{i}U_i\supseteq E}{{\delta\to 0}}}\bigg\{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty (\diam U_i)^d:\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i\supseteq E,\: \diam(U_i)<\delta \bigg\} $$ where we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ seen as a metric space $(X,p)$ and $$ \diam(U_i)=\sup\{p(x,y):x,y\in U_i\}$$ as it's defined in any undergrad analysis course dealing with multi-variate integration.

My problem is that I never studied geometric measure theory, except for  the basic knowledge I acquired in the introductory course in multivariate integration, so I'm finding it hard to find a way from the hypothesis of convexity of the involved sets through its application to the definition of Hausdorff measure.

Comment: As it  is  currently written, your question is phrased as an isolated problem without any additional  context.  Please edit your question to give some more details.   Define your notation, and give precise definitions of the terms you are using (e.g. what is $\mathfrak{H}$?  how do you define the Hausdorff measure? what is $\partial E$?, etc).  If you are working out of a text, a reference to that text would be helpful, as it gives readers an idea of what you might know.  At a bare minimum, explain what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: [This guide on avoiding "no clue" questions may also be helpful.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to do a projection from $\partial(F)$ to $\partial E$.

This is a Lipshitz function with Lipshitz constant 1 and so by the properties of the Hausdorff measure we know that $H^s(f(E))\le L^s (H^s(E))$ and so we are done